# Using PowerShell to convert from Excel XLSX to a tab-delimited file without Excel installed

Tags: excel, xml, powershell, xlsx, xmldocument

We have some automation we're looking to leverage PowerShell for on a Windows box on which Excel cannot be installed, and so I don't have access to Excel COM objects.  My goal is to convert a ~250,000 row Excel file to tab-delimited file for fastload into Teradata.

An idea I had was to decompress the XLSX file (since it's really just a renamed ZIP file anyway) and read the following two XML files: sharedStrings.xml and sheet1.xml.  sharedStrings.xml contains the real cell values and text as referenced in sheet1.xml.

The following seems to work, but only with smaller files.  It goes way too slow with larger files though like I'm trying to automatically convert.  Here's what I've tried so far using PowerShell:

```
$path_shared_strings = "Excel File\xl\sharedStrings.xml"
$path_xml_sheet = "Excel File\xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml"

$xml_shared_strings = New-Object -TypeName "System.Xml.XmlDocument"
$xml_shared_strings.Load($path_shared_strings)

$xml_sheet = New-Object -TypeName "System.Xml.XmlDocument"
$xml_sheet.Load($path_xml_sheet)

$output_file = "test.csv"

$delimited_content = ""
$tot_rows = ($xml_sheet.worksheet.sheetData.row.Count)
$tot_cols = ($xml_sheet.worksheet.sheetData.row[1].c.Count)

for($row_cnt = 0; $row_cnt -le ($tot_rows - 1); $row_cnt++)
{
    $row_string = ""
    for($col_cnt = 0; $col_cnt -le ($tot_cols - 1); $col_cnt++)
    {
        if( $col_cnt -gt 0 ) { $row_string = $row_string + "    " }
        $indexed_value = $xml_sheet.worksheet.sheetData.row[$row_cnt].c[$col_cnt].v
        $actual_value = $xml_shared_strings.sst.si.t[$indexed_value]
        $row_string = $row_string + $actual_value
        if( $col_cnt -eq ($tot_cols - 1) ) { $row_string = $row_string + "`r`n" }
    }
    $delimited_content = $delimited_content + $row_string
}

$delimited_content | out-file $output_file
```

My question is: Is there a better way?  Or if our only non-COM object way is through the XML, is there a better way to convert it to a delimited file?

Comment: You should look at the OpenXML API for Excel.  It will be some work to digest, but it will perform very well.

Comment: Appreciate the idea.  It sounds like it'd require that an Open XML SDK be installed server-side though?  I don't think that's an option, but I can check.

Comment: FWIW, you'll still end up dealing with the XML nodes. Might not be as useful as I was thinking.  For generating docs, definitely.

Comment: have you looked at the many excel modules for powershell? the ImportExcel one seems to be both well received and updated fairly often.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use stringbuilder for string concatenation:

```
[System.Text.StringBuilder]$delimited_content = ""
[System.Text.StringBuilder]$row_string = ""
.
[void]$row_string.Clear()
.
[void]$row_string.Append( $actual_value )
.
[void]$delimited_content.Append($row_string)
.
$delimited_content.ToString() | out-file $output_file
```

Comment: Sure, I can try that.  Is the benefit speed?

Comment: Yes, stringbuilder is much faster.